# How do I findstr (grep) multiple strings?

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file

Below is the example of a log that I use and I want to grab some part of it out to another txt for reporting and version check. I have a problem on separating the information inside it.

```
gdb-7.2-56.el6.x86_64
khmeros-base-fonts-5.0-9.el6.noarch
gdbas-7.2-16.33.el6.noarch
libXfixes-4.0.4-1.el6.x86_64
gdb-7.2-16.33.el6.noarch
abrt-gui-2.0.8-6.el6.x86_64
info-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64
gdb-7.2-56.el5.x86_64
gnome-terminal-2.31.3-7.el6.x86_64
gdb-7.2-16.33.2.el6.x86_64
```

Here is my string; I want to use

```
gdb   el6    x86_64
```

to `grep` the lines:

```
gdb-7.2-56.el6.x86_64
gdb-7.2-16.33.2.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way:

```
$ grep 'gdb.*el6.*x86_64' file
gdb-7.2-56.el6.x86_64
gdb-7.2-16.33.2.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: Or if you don't know the order, `grep gcc file | grep el6 | grep x86_64`

Comment: if i have a lot of file then just use (like file1 file2 file3) $ grep 'gdb.*el6.*x86_64' file* am i right?

Comment: It does not work..........but if i do like this .......... grep 'gdb el6.*x86_64' file...... it can grep out something if i type like you told me it doesn't show a thing  (i dnont know why )

Comment: i think only line with space ........

gdb 7.2-56 el6 x86_64 

it can grep out but if .........


gdb-7.2-56.el6.x86_64..... in the line is like this  you can not multiple grep

Comment: @eathapeking : both the possibilities work fine with the above comamnd

Comment: goshhh    what wrong with my computer then  is it give out the exact same thing  findstr and grep

Comment: findstr gdb new.txt | findstr el6 | findstr x86_64 .......... i have to use like this  or else it not gonna work so sad T^T